# How to resolve Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql error in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I got `Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` error in my site. I don't know why this happened.

I already did uncomment this section in `/includes/config.php`

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Error

> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/includes/src/Varie‌​n_Autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/app/Mage.php on line 37 Warning:
>   include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/xxx/public_html/xxx/xx/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.p‌​hp' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/includes/src:.:/‌​usr/local/lib/php')
>   in /home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/app/Mage.php on line 37 Fatal error:
>   Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/app/Mage.php on line 54

Comment: Please add details error?

Comment: That's a compiler path, has nothing to do with DB adapter. Can you please submit your error in full.

Comment: Warning: include_once(/home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/app/Mage.php on line 37

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/xxx/public_html/xxx/xx/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/includes/src:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/app/Mage.php on line 37

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/app/Mage.php on line 54

Answer (score 0):

This issue originates from invalid permissions of newly added lib directories. You need to fix the permissions by running the following command in your Magento installation's root

`sudo find lib/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Just to be extra certain, I'd also suggest fixing file permissions

`sudo find lib/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`